# Is there any options to add custom css in react-pdf-table?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-pdf

I have used @david.kucsai/react-pdf-table. here is the css code how i implemented.

```
export const TableCellBodyStyle = {
  padding: 5,
  textAlign: "left",
  wordWrap: `break-word`,
  fontSize: 8,
};
```

its works but i donot have full control on table.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is fixed when I used

```
 const styles= StyleSheet.create({
TableCellBodyStyle : {
  padding: 5,
  textAlign: "left",
  fontSize: 8,
};
})
```